# Strong Induction Hypothesis

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, solution-verification

I want to prove using strong induction that if every natural number $n$ satisfies the condition that; if every natural number less than $n$ is in $G$ then $n$ is in $G$ -- $\textbf{then} $ every natural number is in $G$.

Okay so I let $B=\forall k((k\in \mathbb N)\notin G)$. So by contraposition the assumption is that $B$ is nonempty, which should conclude that $G$ is empty. But using the base case $n=0$, I find that $0\notin B$, thus $0\in G$. Then there should exist a least element $l$ such that for all $l$, $l\in B$

But since $l\ne 0$, then I index $l-1$ where $0<l\le(k+1)$. Since $(l-1)\in \mathbb N$, then for all $l$, $l\in G$, thus $B=\emptyset$ which then implies $G\ne \emptyset$, thus $G=\mathbb N$

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

A case can be made that this answer is defective, since it does not try to
critique the OP's efforts.  I wasn't able to follow the OP's work.

For what it's worth, this
is how I would fulfill the task specified in the query's first paragraph.

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $S(n)$ denote the set of all natural numbers $< n.$

Let $G$ be a set that satisfies the following property:

For any $n \in \mathbb{N},$ if $G$ completely contains $S(n)$, then G contains $n$.

To prove: $G$ contains all of $\mathbb{N}.$

Proof:

$G$ contains $S(1)$, which is the empty set, so $G$ contains the natural number $1$.

Inductively assume that for a given $N$, G contains every number between
$1$ and $N$ inclusive.

Then, by definition, $G$ contains $S(N+1)$.

Therefore, $G$ contains $(N+1).$

This completes the strong induction step, so $G$ must contain all of $\mathbb{N}.$